# Deleting JPA entity containing @CollectionOfElements throws ConstraintViolationException

Tags: hibernate, jpa

I'm trying to delete entities which contain lists of Integer, and I'm getting ConstraintViolationExceptions because of the foreign key on the table generated to hold the integers. It appears that the delete isn't cascading to the mapped collection.

I've done quite a bit of searching, but all of the examples I've seen on how to accomplish this are in reference to a mapped collection of other entities which can be annotated; here I'm just storing a list of Integer. Here is the relevant excerpt from the class I'm storing:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="CHANGE_IDS")
@GenericGenerator(
        name = "CHANGE_ID_GEN",
        strategy =  "org.hibernate.id.enhanced.SequenceStyleGenerator",
        parameters = {
                @Parameter(name="sequence_name", value="course_changes_seq"),
                @Parameter(name="increment_size", value="5000"),
                @Parameter(name=" optimizer", value="pooled")
                     }
    )
@NamedQueries ({
    @NamedQuery(
        name="Changes.getByStatus",
        query=  "SELECT c " +
                "FROM DChanges c " +
                "WHERE c.status = :status "),
    @NamedQuery(
            name="Changes.deleteByStatus",
            query=  "DELETE " +
                    "FROM Changes c " +
                    "WHERE c.status = :status ")
})
public class Changes {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator="CHANGE_ID_GEN")
    @Column(name = "ID")
    private final long id;

    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    @Column(name = "STATUS", length = 20, nullable = false)
    private final Status status;

    @Column(name="DOC_ID")
    @org.hibernate.annotations.CollectionOfElements
    @org.hibernate.annotations.IndexColumn(name="DOC_ID_ORDER")
    private List<Integer> docIds;
}
```

I'm deleting the Changes objects using a @NamedQuery:

```
final Query deleteQuery = this.entityManager.createNamedQuery("Changes.deleteByStatus");
deleteQuery.setParameter("status", Status.POST_FLIP);
final int deleted = deleteQuery.executeUpdate();
this.logger.info("Deleted " + deleted + " POST_FLIP Changes");
```

Comment: Can you show how do you delete Changes Entity ???

Comment: are you sure the @Cascade annotation is needed ? i've never seen it before on a @CollectionOfElement. I would try without it if you haven't yet.

Comment: @Arthur I've added the named query I'm using

Comment: @Thierry Right. That was added to try to get the delete to cascade, but it has no effect either way. I've removed it from the code above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An HQL delete doesn't cascade to related **entities** as per the JPA specs (although some user would like an extended behavior as reported in [HHH-695](http://opensource.atlassian.com/projects/hibernate/browse/HHH-695)). From the JPA 1.0 specification:

> #### 4.10 Bulk Update and Delete Operations
>
> (...)
>
> A delete operation only applies to
>   entities of the specified class and
>   its subclasses. It does not cascade to
>   related entities.
>
> (...)

So you're on your own when using a bulk-delete.

However, in the particular case of a `CollectionOfElements` which are not entities (and since there is no way to bulk delete the table for the collection), I would have expected the following to work:

```
@Column(name="DOC_ID")
@org.hibernate.annotations.CollectionOfElements
@org.hibernate.annotations.IndexColumn(name="DOC_ID_ORDER")
@OnDelete(action = OnDeleteAction.CASCADE)
private List<Integer> docIds;
```

But unfortunately, it doesn't, the `SessionFactory` complains with:

```
org.hibernate.MappingException: only inverse one-to-many associations may use on-delete="cascade": com.stackoverflow.q3049451.Changes.docIds
```

According to [this thread](https://forum.hibernate.org/viewtopic.php?f=9&t=971255), this sounds like a bug...

So this leave you with the solution you implemented: perform a select, loop and remove the entities.

Comment: Thanks for the reference to the spec, that sheds some light on the issue.

Answer (score 0):

After much experimentation, I found that using the *Changes.deleteByStatus* named query shown in the question simply won't result in the delete being cascaded to the collection table no matter what combination of annotations I tried.

Ultimately I ended up getting all matching entities with the *Changes.getByStatus* named query and then removing them via the entity manager, which seems to handle the cascading correctly.

```
    final Query query = this.entityManager.createNamedQuery("Changes.getById");
    query.setParameter("status", Status.POST_FLIP);
    List<Changes> changes = query.getResultList();
    for (Changes change : changes) {
        this.entityManager.remove(change);
    }
```

Any other explanations or suggestions are welcome.